# Omnet++/INET Module PeriodicGate forwards Packets even if it is closed

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am new to Omnet and Inet.
I am modifying the network TsnLinearNetwork which is part of the Inet Library and looks like the following:

Client <-------> Switch <-------> Server

The client sends a continuous packet stream which the switch forwards to the server.
I am trying to set up a Periodic Gate which changes its state, so that the packets won't get forwarded, if the gate is closed.
The 1st second the gate should be closed and the 2nd second it should be open.

As a result the gate status changes which I configured in the omnetpp.ini file.
In contrast to that, the packets are forwarded even on a *closed gate state*.

I played around with the omnet.ini parameters without any success.
I am expecting that the packets are discarded when the periodic gate state is closed.
Like the documentation points out:

> **PeriodicGate**
> This module allows or forbids packets to pass through depending on whether the gate is open or closed. The gate is open and closed according to the list of change times periodically.

So here my questions:
**Why are the packets forwarded even on a closed gate state?**
**How can I achieve that behaviour?**

*omnetpp.ini*

```
[General]

[simpleStart03]
network = simpleStart
sim-time-limit = 2s

*.client.numApps = 1
*.client.app[*].typename = "UdpSourceApp"
*.client.app[0].display-name = "random traffic"
*.client.app[*].io.destAddress = "server"
*.client.app[0].io.destPort = 1000
*.client.app[0].source.packetLength = 1000B
*.client.app[0].source.productionInterval = 500us
*.client.hasOutgoingStreams = true
*.client.bridging.streamIdentifier.identifier.mapping = [{stream: "random traffic"}] 
*.client.bridging.streamCoder.encoder.mapping = [{stream: "random traffic", pcp: 0}]

*.server.numApps = 1
*.server.app[*].typename = "UdpSinkApp"
*.server.app[0].io.localPort = 1000

*.switch.bridging.streamCoder.decoder.mapping = [{pcp: 0, stream: "random traffic"}]
*.switch.hasIngressTrafficFiltering = true
*.switch.bridging.streamFilter.ingress.numGates = 1
*.switch.bridging.streamFilter.ingress.numMeters = 1
*.switch.bridging.streamFilter.ingress.numStreams = 1
*.switch.bridging.streamFilter.ingress.classifier.mapping = {"random traffic": 0}
*.switch.bridging.streamFilter.ingress.meter[0].display-name = "random traffic"
*.switch.bridging.streamFilter.ingress.meter[*].typename = "SingleRateTwoColorMeter"
*.switch.bridging.streamFilter.ingress.meter[0].committedInformationRate = 40Mbps
*.switch.bridging.streamFilter.ingress.meter[0].committedBurstSize = 10kB

*.switch.bridging.streamFilter.ingress.gate[*].typename = "PeriodicGate"
*.switch.bridging.streamFilter.ingress.gate[0].display-name = "random traffic"
*.switch.bridging.streamFilter.ingress.gate[0].initiallyOpen = false
*.switch.bridging.streamFilter.ingress.gate[0].durations = [1s,1s]
*.switch.bridging.streamFilter.ingress.gate[*].initiallyOpen = false
```

*omnetpp.ned*

```
import inet.networks.tsn.TsnLinearNetwork;

network simpleStart extends TsnLinearNetwork
{

}
```

omnet Version: 6.0.1
Inet Version: inet4.4

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This issue was stated as a bug**

https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/issues/830

> The bug is that the classifier doesn't check that the selected gate index can be pushed with the packet or not. In case the selected branch has back pressure then the default branch should be selected. If the default branch also has back pressure then an error should be raised.

[This](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/commit/39777a0d198bcc98979d89672d3e1d139a9df92a) Commit fixes the issue and [this](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/commit/5ecb9b9215bf0d493c802132753a9ffd9176eaa6) commit changes the order of the submodules.